# How to upgrade the helm chart deployment using a file

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Below is Helm code to install

```
helm install coreos/kube-prometheus --name kube-prometheum --namespace monitoring -f kube-prometheus.yml
```

by this way we can override the value.yml values with the values present in kube-prometheus.yml.

Is there any way by which we can first install and then update the value.yml from kube-prometheus.yml file.

I can use `helm upgrade releasename kube-prometheum`after changing the value.yml file directly. I don't want that

Use case:
Initially, I used an image with tag 1.0 in value.yml. Now I have below code in kube-prometheus.yml just to update the image tag

```
prometheusconfigReloader:
image:
 tag: 2.0
```

Instead of deleting and creating again. I want to upgrade it. This is just for example, there could be multiple values. that is why I can't use -set.

Comment: Can you give an example of the sequence you're thinking of, and why you'd want it?  I'd recommend just using `helm install -f` once (to not deploy resources with default values and then change them to what you actually want) but this seems to be what you don't want to do.

Comment: @DavidMaze: updated my question. thanks for helping

Answer (score 5):

So you first run `helm install coreos/kube-prometheus --name kube-prometheum --namespace monitoring -f kube-prometheus.yml` with your values file set to point at 1.0 of the image:

```
prometheusconfigReloader:
image:
 tag: 1.0
```

Then you change the values file or create a new values file or even create a new values file containing:

```
prometheusconfigReloader:
image:
 tag: 2.0
```

Let's say this file is called kube-prometheus-v2.yml Then you can run:

`helm upgrade -f kube-prometheus-v2.yml kube-prometheum coreos/kube-prometheus`

Or even:

`helm upgrade -f kube-prometheus.yml -f kube-prometheus-v2.yml kube-prometheum coreos/kube-prometheus`

This is because both values file overrides will be overlaid and according to the [`helm upgrade` documentation](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/helm/helm_upgrade.md) "priority will be given to the last (right-most) value specified".

Or if you've already installed and want to find out what the values file that was used contained then you can use [`helm get values kube-prometheum`](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/helm/helm_get_values.md)

Comment: Thanks. I will try this